# Why myContract.events.MyEvent([options][, callback]) does not return "data" and "logs"?

Tags: web3js, remix, contract-invocation, events, logs

We have an event as follows :

```
event LogNewObject(address sender, bytes32 indexed id, bytes32 sub_states_types, bytes32 sub_states_values, address owner);
```

This event is called in following function :

```
function newObject(bytes32 _id, uint256 number_of_sub_states, bytes32[10] sub_states_types, bytes32[10] sub_states_values, address _owner) public returns(bool success) {
        require(!isObject(_id));

        uint256 counter=0;
        for(counter; counter < number_of_sub_states; counter++) {

            objectStructs[_id].state.sub_state[sub_states_types[counter]] = sub_states_values[counter];

            emit LogNewObject(msg.sender, _id, bytes32(sub_states_types[counter]), bytes32(sub_states_values[counter]), _owner);

        }

        objectStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
        objectStructs[_id].isObject = true;

        objectList.push(_id);

        return true;
    }
```

*I want to get the logs like* **remix** *as following picture shows :*

https://ibb.co/hYZhZS

For this purpose, I use following command :

```
contractInstance.events.LogNewObject({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
```

And I receive following output :

```
> contractInstance.events.LogNewObject({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
null
Subscription {
  id: null,
  callback: [Function],
  arguments: 
   [ { fromBlock: '0x0',
       toBlock: 'latest',
       topics: [Array],
       address: '0xe1623aaf57fcbe260f022404c730ae32aebe39f6' } ],
  _reconnectIntervalId: null,
  options: 
   { subscription: 
      { params: 1,
        inputFormatter: [Array],
        outputFormatter: [Function: bound ],
        subscriptionHandler: [Function: subscriptionHandler] },
     type: 'eth',
     requestManager: 
      RequestManager {
        provider: [HttpProvider],
        providers: [Object],
        subscriptions: {} } },
  subscriptionMethod: 'logs' }
```

As you see, the output is not as it's expected.

I used also the command proposed by user " Jitendra Kumar. Balla". However, I receive same output and not the output similar to the **remix** logs output as I uploaded its screen shot above in my question. **I expect this output:**

[image]

**What option must be added to this command to receive an output similar to *remix* output logs which is shown in above picture ?**

Comment: Try to use contractInstance.events.LogNewObject({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'}, function(error, event){ console.log(JSON.stringify(event)); })

Comment: Which blockchain tools are u using ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [eventEmitter structure](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id38) which is easier to manage and do what you want to do :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I used same structure and command, isn't it ?

Comment: Where is your `console.log` or debugger breakpoint in your code?